# Anyone know how to build a neural network in simulink using "Neural Network Tool" and load parameter?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm, simulink, toolbox

Anyone know how to build a neural network in simulink using "Neural Network Tool" and load parameter?

Currently I want to create CNN and LSTM, but I dno't know how to deal with those blocks(control system, Net Input Functions, Processing Functions, Transfer Functions and Weight Functions).

And search on google, but get no examples. So I ask here, could anyone provide an example? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You would design your network in MATLAB (possibly using the `nntool` or `nnstart` GUI functionality) and then use [gensim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/gensim.html) to generate the Simulink model for the network.